# CAT5e in new home doesn’t work

Tags: wiring, ethernet

We just moved into our new house and found out that there are cat5e ports all over the house. I plugged in our router to the port and my pc into another but it doesn’t work. I found them all in a room downstairs and am wondering if they’re  wired correctly. Two of them were just cut and disconnected from the rest so I connected them in the same way the others were but still nothing. They’re only connected by the blue wires and the blue and white wires which idk if that’s right or wrong. If you could help me out to get this working that would be great.

[image]

Comment: I don't know that I've ever seen old school CAT3/POTS wire terminated in wire nuts like that. That's... impressive...

Comment: That's a 4-pointed "star" configuration. We can't tell what's been done elsewhere, but "daisy chain" is where you have a jack with one cable coming in and another cable going out. Assuming that one of these cables probably leads outside to the NID, you can get from this point to whatever the first jack on each cable is via re-terminating correctly and using a switch, so probably 3 jacks. If *those* jacks have other cables leading out from them, they would have to be removed, as *those* would be the "daisy-chain" connections we can't support (unless via a 3-port switch at the jack location.)

Comment: Newly built home, or newly-purchased existing home?

Comment: When you write "cat5e", do you mean "Something that looks like I could plug my computer in to it", or did you actually check the cables?

Comment: The ports may be 5e, but with wiring like that the cabling definitely no longer is.

Comment: @Mast The  cabling is what it is. The present installation is clearly not, but that **does not change the class of the cable** it's made from, nor affect the class of the result you can get by re-terminating the cable properly for 5e.

Comment: @Ecnerwal You're right. I should've said the wiring system is no longer 5e. The cables themselves didn't change of-course.

Comment: You've got phone wiring, installed by a phone guy, using cheaper UTP cable that might be catX rated.  **What did you ask for in your building contract ?**

Comment: @Criggie 95% odds they bought an existing home with existing wiring that's only new to them, and didn't specify anything. There's nothing here that suggests this is a new build, and plenty that suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Ecnerwal oh yeah sorry - I read "we moved into our new home" as a "new home" rather than "new-to-us"

Comment: Borrow some certification tester like Fluke DSX 5000/8000, at least DTX 1800. Basically every cable unraveling has to be within the limits of the standard. You have two options, learn enough about wired cabling sytems or save your time and pay some professional.

Comment: My DSL connection uses 4 wires of the CAT6 cable at the household panel where the DSL comes in from the outside. The wiring looks like the photo. The other end of that cable has all 8 wires hooked up to a CAT6 wall box, but only 4 of them are used in the DSL adapter that plugs into my modem. The CAT6 adapter just makes it easier to diconnect and reconnect the modem. Future improvement may need all 8 wires, and no new wiring needs to be installed because the extra 4 wires are already there.

Answer (score 28):

They are wired correctly for telephone (POTS, Plain Old Telephone Service, single pair) per your description.

To use them for ethernet would require re-terminating, and depending how they are run, possibly some won't work (things that work fine for POTS don't for ethernet, such as multiple connection points on one cable.) You might get lucky if they are in fact all single runs from the central location, in which case a patch panel and switch there would allow distribution to all the other locations.

You should identify what cable leads outside where the telephone company Network Interface Device is, and NOT attempt to connect ethernet to that one.

10/100 Mb ethernet needs two pairs, gigabit ethernet needs all 4 pairs, and you can't just wirenut them together...

Comment: Yeah. Buy a crimper, a bunch of RJ45 jacks (I'd suggest a box of 50 - they'll be cheaper per, plus when you're learning you'll get more than a few wrong), and a cable tester to make sure they're crimped correctly. The whole batch can probably be had for under $100.

Comment: Nope. Done right, you punchdown into jacks (them are the female bits), and use factory-made patch cables anywhere you require a plug (the male bits that crimp.) They can be had cheaper than the parts to make 'em. Crimping plugs onto solid wall cable is not generally reliable and not recommended as a result. Plus, an inexpensive punchdown tool is less expensive than a decent crimper. And punchdowns can be re-done if you mess up, rather than cut-off-and-throw-away. You also don't need a cable tester if you have two things that will indicate that they are connecting at gigabit speed, or not.

Comment: Okay, could you point me in the direction of a previous post or something that gives a detailed description of how to go through with that please.

Comment: I don't think there's any post here that will transform complete ignorance of how ethernet wiring is correctly accomplished to knowledge of how to do it. That's a very large amount of learning, it's entirely possible to do it (ignorance is curable) but it comes closer to being a book than something in the scope of this site. We have a number of similar questions, but none of the answers I've glanced at suit that purpose. Most of the other websites I've looked at in hopes of finding you one are either attempting to upsell products or full of misinformation (or both.)

Comment: But someone else may have a site suggestion. I'm a poor source for a website for starting from scratch, as I started from scratch before there was a world-wide web (and I can connect 10Base5 cables with vampire taps - which is an utterly useless skill for decades now.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE5

Comment: pssst. Hey man, you wanna buy some 50 ohm resistors? *Real* cheap....

Comment: A cable tester would be a great investment in almost any case - you'll need to trace the cables to work out where they go and if you're reterminating them, to at least do a minimal functional check

Comment: My first Ethernet/twisted pair tester was an [STM-8](https://amzn.to/3vmkmd4) but now there are plenty of much less expensive testers, and even the cheapest will (unless DOA) get the job done.

Comment: @DevinSchutz this has all the basics for re-terminating the wirenut end in a keystone block. https://youtu.be/0gxNZoPcnP4 Tracing the cable is more difficult, as stated above you want to know which one goes to the phone service and NOT use that one, and preferably which cable goes to which room's jack.

Comment: I don't believe anyone mentioned that if the original cable was for POTS, he'll lose phone service on cables being rewired for internet/ethernet.  Also, I've done RJ45 plugs on Cat5 and cat6, and, to be honest, it's tricky to get right:  All the wires have to be precisely stripped, and getting each individual wire into the proper slots in the plug is not easy.  Lastly, we need to know the cable category (Cat 3, Cat5, Cat 6).  If Cat-3 (which I don't think it is bc it's blue), you'll have slow connections.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I strongly doubt the questioner has landline phone service.  That's an expensive thing only old people do these days, and not even all old people. And I have not suggested putting plugs on the cable - exactly the opposite - jacks with punchdown connectors are much easier to wire, plugs, you buy with a patch cable already installed and already tested. Questioner states cables are 5e.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  good point, I missed that he said it was all cat-5.   Still, you have to be precise on making it all work. All runs need to be terminated in an ethernet switch or router, you can't just wire-nut them together and expect it to work.  Also, that comment you made about land lines is pretty offensive and prejudicial, please refrain for making comments like that again. 

In a humorous aside:  What does ethernet stand for?   it's to catch the etherbunny!    I'll probably snipped for this, but who cares.

Comment: Funny thing is we have POTS landline, and, so far the phone company hasn't made a great case for dropping it. Its outlasted ... analog mobile, GSM, 2G and 3 different physical./wired data formats, maybe 4....  course its so old I don't think it was ever on cat 5 like newer builds

Comment: Still have one, but it's purely inertia (dealing with the annoyance of porting the number to a cell phone.) It costs 3x what a cheap cell plan does, or the same as a better cell plan (or less than an overpriced cell plan) and primarily gets spam calls (and no handy spam-call-blocking as with a cell phone.) Fortunately we don't live in a dead zone so we can get rid of it, and will. The phone company makes no case for getting rid of it (other than charging too much) - they enjoy the fat profits from old infrastructure.

Comment: With an oldschool wired phone, it also handles power going down - we have one as a backup 'in case'. Not sure of what tho, meanwhile we switched from cable to fibre entirely here :D

Answer (score 12):

Yikes!POTS wiring is usually done in a daisy topology (from one jack to the next), no way will that work with IP protocol/Ethernet/internet, it  has to be wired in a star topology (each jack having a home run to the router or modem).  if wired as POTS, you have a lot of work to do...also, if the structure of the of the home makes it difficult to run home runs, you might consider WIFI  for some locations.  If devices you might have don't have WIFI capability, you can connect another router in bridge mode, then it appears like a hard wired connection to the device.

Comment: Or put in switches wherever the POTS splits into 2 or more wires. May be more expensive, but easier.

Answer (score 4):

For 10/100Mbps you need 2 pairs, for gigabit you need all 4 pairs.

Due to high frequency signals involved, cables need to be terminated properly so their impedance stays constant through the line. Using wire nuts like that will create an impedance discontinuity which will destroy the signal integrity (ie, Ethernet won't work). So you will have to get rid of all the wire nuts anyway.

So, first you need to map how the wires are connected in the house. If this was used for phones, you could have outlets connected in daisy chain, and that won't work. Ethernet needs a star topology, with a cable from each outlet to the switch, and outlets can't be daisy chained.

You can open all the outlets. If there's only one cable inside and no sign of daisy chaining, you're on the right track. You should also check all the 8 wires are connected to each socket, because if the installation was wired for phone use only, maybe they didn't bother. Also time to check the jacks are Cat5 with 8 contacts and not just plain phone jacks. Google "RJ45 wiring" for which color goes where.

Once you've figured that out, you can buy an Ethernet patch panel and install it where all the cables come out (in the picture in the question). Then you can connect all the cables and wire the panel to your switch/router with short cheap patch cables.

Connecting an Ethernet device will just tell you "doesn't work" or "100 Mbps only" (which means the 2 center pairs are correct) or "gigabit" (which means all 4 pairs are correct). You can also get an Ethernet cable tester, this will usually give more detailed information about which wires are wired wrong.

If there are more wire nuts inside the walls, though, it won't work.

It's not difficult to do, but if you've never done it before, you should check for documentation and tutorials online.

Comment: Technically splicing with wirenuts _will_ work (assuming star topology), but the error rate will be so high that bandwidth will be very low. [It is worth noting that "technically correct" is the worst kind of correctness, of course]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun fact: Ethernet jacks (RJ45) are designed to be backwards compatible with their Phone (RJ11) counterparts. If you look at any Ethernet wiring diagram, pins 4 and 5 are the blue wires in all forms of Ethernet, which is what they are using in your wires here.

If I were you, here's what I would do: change out your RJ11 for RJ45 jacks on **both** ends (wall plates and your basement). For the end in your basement, you can buy what's called a patch (or punch) panel. You'll want a [punch-down tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0072K1QHM) for this project. Also, you'll want to note which cable goes where, as you connect them (a wire tracing tool like a tone generator can be helpful for this). The other end will entail installing keystones (which are the same as your punch panel) and wall plates for the keystones. Once you have your wires terminated as RJ45, you can then plug the patch panel to a switch and connect the switch to your Internet and have a fully functional home network.

Comment: While there are no pictures of that end, I assume they actually have RJ-45s as wall jacks, since they plugged in the router and PC. Likely even "Cat5e" RJ45s, as I read the question. Likely with only the blue pair connected, of course.

Comment: Do phones do that? I thought phones use RJ11s, and they look like smaller RJ45s Also I suspect simply installing keystones on either end, then plugging in one and and testing would be the lazy solution, especially since keystones arn't crimped

Comment: They do. You can wire the blue wires up and stick an RJ11 plug into a RJ45 jack and it will work.